# error converting data type varchar to float attached prc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_CUSTPARAM](
    [CUSTTYPE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PARAMETER] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DATATYPE] [int] NULL,
    [TEXT_PARAM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RANGE_FROM] [int] NULL,
    [RANGE_TO] [int] NULL,
    [RATING] [int] NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TABLENAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [COLUMNNAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SQLQUERY] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [SRNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WEIGHT] [numeric](4, 0) NULL,
    [RANGE_VIEW_NAME] [varchar](200) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_CUSTPARAM](
    [CUSTNO] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RATING] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TEMP_CUSTPARAM] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CUSTNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

-------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_CUSTPERSONAL](
    [CUSTNO] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SEX] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MARITALSTATUS] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [INCOMESOURCE] [int] NULL,
    [OCCUPATION] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERSNAME1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERPHNO1] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERADDR1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [YEARSOFSERVICE1] [numeric](30, 2) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERSNAME2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERPHNO2] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERADDR2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [YEARSOFSERVICE2] [numeric](30, 2) NULL,
    [TOTALYEAROFSERVICE] [numeric](30, 2) NULL,
    [NOOFDEPENDANTS] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CURRANNUALINCOME] [numeric](30, 3) NULL,
    [QUALIFICATION] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DESIGNATION] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [VERIFICATIONTYPE] [int] NULL,
    [PURPOSEOFACCOUNT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [REFEREDBY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ANTICIPATEDACTIVITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NI_NUMBER] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [IDENTIFICATION_MARK] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PKID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TXNTURNOVER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MONTHLY_INCOME] [numeric](30, 3) NULL,
    [FATHER_SPOUSE_NAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [MOBILENO] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERTYPE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PROFESSIONTYPE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [BUSINESSTYPE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [AREAOFOCCUPATION] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [EXPTXNPERQTR] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [TYPEOF4WHEELEROWN] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [NATIONALITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MINORYN] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [SRCITIZENYN] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [FORM60_61YN] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [PASSPORT_NO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IF_SELF_EMPLOYED] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IF_BUSINESS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SOURCE_OF_INCOME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [YOU_LIVE_IN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [YOUR_RESIDENCE_IS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DI_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [REC_UPDATEDT] [datetime] NULL,
    [DAILY_INCOME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERPHNO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERADDR] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [YEARSOFSERVICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FIRSTNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MIDDLENAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LASTNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PLACEOFBIRTH] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PASSPORT_YN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMIRATESID_YN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESIVISA_YN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SALCERTIFICATE_YN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYMENT_STATUS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERSNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [E_ADDRESS2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [E_ADDRESS3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [E_COUNTRY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [YEAROFSERVICE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DEPENDENT_CHILDREN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SPOUSE_EMP_STATUS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ACCOMODATION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PROFESSION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESVISANO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESVISAISSUEPLACE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESVISAISSUEDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESVISAEXPIRYDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMP_CODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PREV_EMPLOYER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMP_JOIN_DATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ACCOUNTOPERATEDBY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESIDENT_STATUS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CREDIT_CARDNO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ISSED_BY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EXPIRY_DATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SCHEME_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TENURE_SCHEME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INSTALLAMT_SCHEME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NOOFINSTALL_SCHEME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MATURITYAMT_SCHEME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MONTHLYAMT_SCHEME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TERM_DEPOSIT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DATE_OF_ISSUE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DATE_OF_MATURITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TERMDEPO_AMOUNT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TERMDEPO_RENEWAL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TERMDEPO_RATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INTIAL_DEPOSIT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SPECIAL_INST] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NAME_CONTACTPERSON] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NAME_CONTACTNUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MODIFIED_ON] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MODIFIED_BY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MOTHERSMAIDENNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_FIRSTNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_LASTNAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_MIDDLENAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERCITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERSTATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERZIP] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RESIDENTCOUNTRY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EMPLOYERCOUNTRYCODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [INRODU_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RISKCATEGORY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ENTITY_GROUP_CODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ACCTNO_INTRO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ENTITY_CODE] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TB_CUSTPERSONAL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CUSTNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
----------------------------------------------------------


create
PROCEDURE    PROC_CUSTRATING_INC
 @WEIGHTAGE FLOAT,
@TAB_NAME VARCHAR(4000), 
@COL_NAME VARCHAR(4000)
--@ENTITY_CODE VARCHAR(50),@ENTITY_GROUP_CODE VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @v_DAT_ DATETIME,
 @v_DAT2 DATETIME,
 @v_Pro_ VARCHAR(100),
 @v_LAS_ DATETIME,
 @v_SQL_ VARCHAR(500),
 @v_COU_ FLOAT,
 @v_TOT_ FLOAT,
 @v_BAT_ FLOAT,

 @v_SQLSTRING VARCHAR(1000)


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @v_DAT_=GETDATE();
SET @v_Pro_='PROC_CUSTRATING_INC';

DELETE FROM TEMP_CUSTPARAM;

 SELECT @v_LAS_ = LASTRUNDT FROM TB_SCHEDULE WHERE PROCESS_ID ='2';
SET  @v_SQLSTRING = 'INSERT INTO /*+ APPEND*/ TEMP_CUSTPARAM(CUSTNO, RATING)
SELECT DISTINCT Q.CUSTNO, ISNULL(((ISNULL(P.RATING,0) * '+ ISNULL(@WEIGHTAGE, '') +')/100),0) AS RATING
FROM '+ ISNULL(@TAB_NAME, '') +' Q INNER JOIN TB_CUSTPARAM P
ON Q.' + ISNULL(@COL_NAME, '') +'=P.TEXT_PARAM
AND P.TABLENAME='''+ ISNULL(@TAB_NAME, '') +''' AND P.COLUMNNAME='''+ ISNULL(@COL_NAME, '') +'''
AND TRUNC(Q.DI_DATE) >= '''+ ISNULL(@v_LAS_, '') +''' ';


PRINT 'v_SQLSTRING111=== ' + ISNULL(@v_SQL_, '');
EXECUTE (@v_SQLSTRING);

-- RETURN;
MERGE INTO TB_RATING_TEMP A
USING TEMP_CUSTPARAM E
ON (A.CUSTNO=E.CUSTNO)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
A.TEMP_RATING=ISNULL(E.RATING,0);

SET  @v_SQLSTRING='UPDATE TB_RATING_TEMP A
SET
A.PARAMCOUNT=A.PARAMCOUNT + 1,
A.BRATING = NVL(A.BRATING,0) + NVL(A.TEMP_RATING,0)
WHERE
A.CUSTNO IN
(
SELECT Q.CUSTNO
FROM TB_CUSTPARAM P,'+ ISNULL(@TAB_NAME, '') +' Q
WHERE P.TEXT_PARAM=TO_CHAR(Q.'+ ISNULL(@COL_NAME, '') +')
)';

PRINT 'v_SQLSTRING222=== ' + ISNULL(@v_SQL_, '');
EXECUTE (@v_SQLSTRING);
PRINT 4;
SET @v_DAT2=GETDATE();
--PRINT  'PROCEDURE ' + ISNULL(@v_Pro_, '') + ' TAKES : ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, trunc((((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)/60)/24)), '') + ' Days ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,  trunc(((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)/60)- 24*(trunc((((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)/60)/24))), '') + ' Hrs. ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,  trunc((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)- 60*(trunc(((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)/60)) ), '') + ' Mins.'  + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, trunc(86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))- 60*ISNULL((trunc((86400*(@v_DAT2-@v_DAT_))/60)), '') + ' Sec.'), '');
  END;
```

Running

```
EXEC PROC_CUSTRATING_INC  11.0,'TB_CUSTPERSONAL','OCCUPATION'
```

results in the error

> error converting data type varchar to float.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is in the below statement

```
SET  @v_SQLSTRING = 'INSERT INTO /*+ APPEND*/ TEMP_CUSTPARAM(CUSTNO, RATING)
SELECT DISTINCT Q.CUSTNO, ISNULL(((ISNULL(P.RATING,0) * '+ ISNULL(@WEIGHTAGE,     '') +')/100),0) AS RATING
FROM '+ ISNULL(@TAB_NAME, '') +' Q INNER JOIN TB_CUSTPARAM P
ON Q.' + ISNULL(@COL_NAME, '') +'=P.TEXT_PARAM
AND P.TABLENAME='''+ ISNULL(@TAB_NAME, '') +''' AND P.COLUMNNAME='''+     ISNULL(@COL_NAME, '') +'''
AND TRUNC(Q.DI_DATE) >= '''+ ISNULL(@v_LAS_, '') +''' ';
```

The `ISNULL(@WEIGHTAGE, '')` should be changed to `ISNULL(@WEIGHTAGE, 0.0)` since @WEIGHTAGE is a `float` and you are trying to change a varchar `''` to a `float` in this `ISNULL` statement which is causing it to fail.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Is this sqlserver? I see `TRUNC(Q.DI_DATE)` and I don't think this is valid in sqlserver, I get an error when I tried in sqlfiddle in SQL2008 and SQL2014. Could you confirm what database and version this is? Also could you post the whole output from the console when you execute the sp?